# Why does GCloud App Engine not update the deployed SvelteKit website after I edit the files?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, svelte, sveltekit

I have successfully been able to deploy my SvelteKit App through GCloud App Engine, but whenever I update my code and deploy again, my website does not change.

I was expecting the SvelteKit template App to change to my Svelte app on deploy, but it did not change. Additionally, I have been able to run the App locally, and can see the new changes through that.

Comment: Can you check your version on App Engine and be sure that the traffic is served to the latest revision?

Comment: Are you running `npm run build` before you deploy? "build" generates (in this case, Updates) the files that will be deployed. Plus, after running build, you could also run `npm run preview` to see how the deployed site will look like.